# Why does semaphore not affected by post from different thread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Semaphore is defined as static variable

```
static int semaphore = -1;
```

I am trying to post to this semaphore

```
sem_post(&semaphore);
```

There is a wait for semaphore in the thread created this way:

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, start, NULL);
```

and

```
static void *start(void *context)
{
    // ...

    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);    
    sem_wait(&semaphore);

    // ...

    return NULL;
}
```

Somehow wait for semaphore is not affected by semaphore post. If I post for semaphore from start routine everything is ok.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `int*` instead of `sem_t*` as the first parameter of `sem_xxx` functions may access memory past the allocated region. According to at least one [source of `<semaphore.h>`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/refs/tags/android-4.1.1_r4/sysroot/usr/include/bits/semaphore.h), the size of `sem_t` is 16 to 32 bytes; `int` is not going to be sufficient to hold the structure of a semaphore, potentially resulting in undefined behavior.

You need to change

```
static int semaphore = -1;
```

to

```
static sem_t semaphore;
```

to fix the access past the allocated memory region.

Also, it is generally a good idea to initialize your semaphores *before* starting the threads that use them. You should move the initialization call from the `start()` function to the `main()`, or whatever function that you use to start your thread.

```
sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
```

Comment: And initialize it with `sem_init`.

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the note! Although OP already calls `sem_init`, I think it would be better to call it outside the thread code. I edited the answer to mention this. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, `sem_init` immediately followed by `sem_wait` on the same semaphore is always a logic error, because there's no way to synchronize on the semaphore being initialized.

Comment: @R -what??  'synchronize on the semaphore' - what?  Since when do semaphores require explicit synchronization?